# transfer Learning in regression for similar domain but different distr

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-mining, transfer-learning

I am currently working on a KDD project aiming to build a predictor with very small real world data.
The goal is to predict to predict the quantity Y of an instance of an Product while knowing other quantities of this instance.
There are Predictors (same Task) trained on similar (not the same) products. Those Models are valid for their use-case.

My approach is to use large datasets of other products (similar domain, similar task but different distributions) and adapt those to the target domain using transfer Learning.

At this pint I am having trouble finding methods/algorithms fitting my needs.
Looking at the decision tree [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHpvx.png) it should be a domain adaption problem.

What algorithm or Model is suited for this kind of usecase?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Deep Domain Adaptation Regression method, as shown in the paper "Representation Subspace Distance for Domain Adaptation Regression" published in ICML 2021. Using the labeled source domain and unlabeled target domain to learn a model performing well on target domain.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome Domain Adaptation Python Toolbox (ADAPT) is an open source library providing access to numerous models and algorithms to perform transfer learning and domain adaptation: https://adapt-python.github.io/adapt/index.html.